# Exporting TextAreaInput as .txt file

Tags: r, shiny

Can you please share with me an example of a shiny app where the content of a textAreaInput is exported as .txt file using a download button.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textAreaInput("text", "Enter text:"),
  downloadButton("download", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "textarea.txt"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      cat(input$text, file=file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, that was exactly what i'm looking for.